# What 2 block tall mob in Minecraft drops the most xp?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been wanting to know what 2 block tall mob in Minecraft drops the most XP can someone tell me the answer I'm trying to make a mob spawner XP farm on Minecraft

Comment: The wiki is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Blazes give the most xp.

Try this design if you dont hv much resources

But to be honest, spawner farms dont give u much xp, try build a pigmen farm if you rlly wanna grind xp